# Need an efficient mysql database schema to store points/ratings

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

I have four main tables-

```
1.user(user_id, name,...) 
2. post(post_id, description, ...) 
3.comment(comment_id,user_id,comment,...)
4.reply(reply_id,user_id, reply,...)
```

and

```
5.user_post(user_id,post_id)
6.post_comment(post_id,comment_id)
```

Now user can give points 1 to 10 (similar to rating) to each comment,reply and post and I also need to count the total points earned by a user with their contents(post,comment,reply). Currently I have two options.

**option 1:**
I can have a big table named `points` and store the number of points for each content with a `type` column which sacrifices `referential integrity` E.g.-

```
points(content_id, type, point, given_by)
```

OR,

**option 2:**
Having three separate tables which doesn't sacrifice `referential integrity`. E.g.-

```
post_point(post_id, point, given_by)
comment_point(comment_id, point, given_by)
reply_point(reply_id, point, given_by)
```

So, what would be the best and future proof option here or Is there any better solution ?? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand the difference between post, comment and reply entities... I think it is ONE entity organized as a multi-root tree.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the Stackoverflow database, as this appears to be quite similar.

Comment: any suggestions regarding to my options @Lennart

Comment: I vote for Option 2:  It makes it easy to get, say, `AVG(point) WHERE post_id=123`